# How can you make it easy for users to install multiple python modules at once?

Tags: python, user-interface, module, installation

I'm currently working on a python project and am trying to allow a user to run a 'setup' type file that will automatically install modules such as pyserial etc. for them very easily. I don't want to give them a text file with info such as:

pip install module_name

and ask them to copy and paste this into terminal. Any suggestions on how I could make the installations tidy and minimalist?

Thanks!

Comment: How is telling them to run `pip install module_name` worse than telling them to run some other command?

Comment: You probably want to define one more module that has all the other modules as dependencies, so that they are installed automatically when the first module is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pip freeze or generate the file yourself.

Examples
Generate output suitable for a requirements file.

```
$ pip freeze
docutils==0.11
Jinja2==2.7.2
MarkupSafe==0.19
Pygments==1.6
Sphinx==1.2.2
Generate a requirements file and then install from it in another environment.

$ env1/bin/pip freeze > requirements.txt # Generate the file
$ env2/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt # Install the requirements
```

For more info please visit:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/

If you are using setup_tools you can also use a requirements file like this:
https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/

```
install_requires=[
   'A>=1',
   'B>=2'
]
```

This should be in your setup.py.

Comment: Hey James thanks for your help! This solves my issue :)

Comment: If this solves your issue, it would be awesome, if you could accept this answer :)